# Table View Cell Height Dynamically + load from .xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I m using a `UITableView` and several custom cells. Each cell has his own height (the cells include `UICollectionView`, `UITableView` and some more customs `UIView`).
More then this, the customs cells (all of them) load from `.xib`.

Basically, the cell height should be determine from the Model (mvc) or it is `static`.

In My case, I can determine the cell's height after I instantiate each one of them, e.i `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` or `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (I don't care about reuse, It's not the point here), because I need to inflate the cell's content.

As far as I know the methods calls of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` isn't documented, therefore I don't need to consider their calls order.

How can I determine cell's height **without instantiate**  it? And without `Magic numbers`.

Comment: as per you question, did you mean that you want to determine the height of the cell at runtime?

Comment: @Vizllx,  Yes, my cell's height are depend on network responses.

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate row heights in following UITableViewDelegate methods based on your model

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If your height calculation is based on network response, update your data model when response is received and call [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: Thanks for bother, But please, read my question again. And I know how `UIItableView` works with static height. I asked about dynamic.

Comment: If your height calculation is based on network response, update your data model when response is received and call [self.tableView reloadData]

Comment: What U offer here is bad performance. `reloadData` isn't good for me here.

Comment: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths might be handy for u... If you want performance as well...

Comment: Same issue m8. I can't reload the cell, I won't solve my problem. Need to find smarter way to handle this.